# How to convert a string into a conditional expression

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, expression

Forgive me if this has already been asked, I looked and I couldn't find a similar question anywhere. I need to convert a string that contains conditional statements, sometimes nested inside one another into visual basic code .

The following are examples of strings as they are stored in my db

```
1) If ([3] =’M’ AND [4] =’S’ AND [5]>=1000 : “OK”;  “VIP”) 
2) If ([3] =’M’ AND [4] =’S’ AND [5]>=1000 : “OK”) Else  “VIP”

1) If ([3] = ‘M’ AND [4] = ‘S’ AND [5]>=1000 : 20/100 * [5]; 500)
2) If ([3] = ‘M’ AND [4] = ‘S’ AND [5]>=1000 : 20/100 * [5]) Else 500

1)If  ([1] >=60 :  50; If ([1]>=50 :  40; If ([1]>=40 : 30; If([1]>=30 : 20;0))))
2) If  ([1] >=60 :  50) Else If ([1]>=50 : 40) Else If ([1]>=40 : 30)  Else If ([1]>=30 : 20) Else 0
```

I know that using CodeDomProvider I can compile and run code in any .net language , but before I do that, I need to have a string formatted in a way the compiler can understand it, in other words I need that an input string like this

```
If  ([1] >=60 :  50; If ([1]>=50 :  40; If ([1]>=40 : 30; If([1]>=30 : 20;0))))
```

end up this way :

```
    If  ([1] >=60) Then 
        Return 50
    ElseIf ([1]>=50) Then
        Return 40
    ElseIf ([1]>=40 ) Then
        Return 30
    ElseIf([1]>=30 ) Then
        Return 20
    Else
        Return 0
    End If
```

P.S. (1) and (2) are the same , being (2) just an alternative way of recording the (1) expression

**The numbers inside square brackets are the ID's of my variables (1 = Age ,2 = NumOfChildren, 3 = Gender ,4 = Status, 5 = Income)**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Please reopen my question !!! I've already explained what happened**

Comment: What are you trying to achive exactly?

Comment: sorry that's not what I tried to ask it's just that I accidentally pressed enter.Now I'm trying to edit

Comment: please wait just a little it was an accident :'(

Comment: @AgentFire but you have already voted to close the question and all because I made a mistake and then it took me while to correct it  because I still find it hard to express myself in English

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken  Please :( it is really urgent , it was just a accident !!! Please reopen the question

Comment: I have voted down and I have just undone it.

Comment: please reopen my question !!! I've already explained what happened